# Click function for next node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a function on image tag `click` but I can't use id as image tag is dynamic and have different ids and I also cant use `on-click` directly on image tag. I tried below jQuery but it didn't worked is there any other way with which i can call function.

```
<input class="select_tattoos_yes" type="checkbox"  />
<img id="dynamic" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select_tattoos_yes").next('img').click(function() {
        alert(1);                          
    });
});
```

Comment: Why no add a `class` to image?

Comment: check your console... if there is any error..

Comment: it works..you have to click on image see : http://jsfiddle.net/q8T8D/

Comment: image is dynamic and if i add class it will add class to all img tag

Comment: do you want to call a function on click of checkbox or on image?

Comment: Yes its working on the fiddle but not my side i have to see why thanks..

Comment: The code is working! Propably you have en error before this code so the script stops before.

Answer (score 1):

you must use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as you have suggested that image are dynamically added.
`.click` works only when the element is already present in the DOM but You need to work on future element

#### HTML

```
<input class="select_tattoos_yes" type="checkbox"  />
<img id="dynamic" alt="image" title="image" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click',':checkbox+img',function() {
    alert('alert done');                          
});
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/q8T8D/1/)

Comment: Looking at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it looks as though the jQuery `click` implementation is just a shortcut for `on`